# Android Service Which method is called when System restarts service using start Sticky

Tags: android, android-service

According to Android documentation here:

[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent, int, int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int))

`onStartCommand()` is fired only if user explicitly starts service

Which method is called when system starts service which was started using `START_STICKY`?

Answer (score 1):

The `Service` will be recreated.

Both `onCreate()` and `onStartCommand()` will be called.

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY):

> Later the system will try to re-create the service. Because it is in
>   the started state, **it will guarantee to call onStartCommand(Intent,
>   int, int) after creating the new service instance**; if there are not
>   any pending start commands to be delivered to the service, it will be
>   called with a null intent object, so you must take care to check for
>   this.